# Wordpress: erro no getResults

Tags: php, wordpress

boa tarde a todos, estou tendo este erro no wordpress:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in 
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\CorretoraWP\wp-content\plugins\clientes\api\lista.php
>   on line 11

**O código da página em questão:**

```
<?php

$x = require_once '../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php';


var_dump($x);

global $wpdb;

$sel = "select * from cliente limit 10";
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sel, ARRAY_N);

print_r($res);
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 1):

O `$wpdb` é `NULL`, ou seja não existe, não foi instanciado.

Então, o `wp-db.php` só contém a classe `class wpdb {...}` e **não** contém a variavel, para usar você deve incluir o header, assim:

```
require_once 'wp-blog-header.php';

$sel = "select * from cliente limit 10";
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sel, ARRAY_N);

print_r($res);
```

Note que `global $wpdb;` é só necessário dentro de funções, por exemplo:

```
require_once 'wp-blog-header.php';

function foobar() {
    global $wpdb;

    $sel = "select * from cliente limit 10";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($sel, ARRAY_N);

    print_r($res);
}


foo();
```